# File reading in C. Complications with fread function

Tags: c, file-io, fread

I'm reading an input file and I am having complications regarding reading each line in it. My input file has two types of records. One has 52 characters while the other has 926. I don't know what to do with my fread function so that it can handle both records. Can anyone help me out? thanks

```
#define LINESZ 927     /* one extra byte for new line */
int num;               /* integer for line number */
char buffer[LINESZ];   /* buffer for file read line */

int main()
{
    FILE *ifp, *ofp;

    ifp = fopen("dd:INPUTF", "r");
    ofp = fopen("dd:OUTPUTF", "w");

    while (!feof(ifp)) {
        if (num = (fread(buffer, sizeof(char), LINESZ, ifp))) {
            if (buffer[22] == 'O') {
                printf("ravroot, %c\n", buffer[22]);
                printf("%s*\n", buffer);
            }
            else if (buffer[22] == 'A') {
                printf("ravrate, %c\n", buffer[22]);
                printf("%s*\n", buffer);
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(ifp);
    fclose(ofp);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You need to add length of record in file.

Comment: Please post the code and the errors you are seeing

Comment: I adjusted my code to reading 927 characters to handle both. but everytime it reads the record with 52 characters, it gets characters from the record next to it until it satisfies the 926 length.

Comment: I'm not having any errors @MoMo. Just wrong output.

Comment: @entendezEJ you open two files input for read and output for write right? But where you use output file pointer?

Comment: I'm going to use it later on after I get the output right @Jayesh. :)

Comment: Do you have every record in a single line?

Comment: No @halex. I have them seperated. Each record having one line.

Comment: Is there something in the record (preferebly at the begining , but , at least within the first 52 bytes) that will identify the record type?

Comment: yup. it has the word "ravroot" and "ravrate" in the beginning of the records. @JamesAnderson

Comment: See [here](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-58.html) for why you should never use `feof` to exit a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading lines from a file, you should use the `fgets` function.  Note however, that `fgets` will write the newline character to your buffer, so you need to strip the newline out. The resulting code looks like this

```
#define LINESZ 1024    /* lots of extra bytes, memory is cheap */
char buffer[LINESZ];   /* buffer for file read line */

int main( void )
{
    int length;
    FILE *ifp, *ofp;

    ifp = fopen("dd:INPUTF", "r");
    ofp = fopen("dd:OUTPUTF","w");

    while( fgets( buffer, LINESZ, ifp ) != NULL )
    {
        // remove the newline character, if any
        length = strlen( buffer );
        if ( length > 0 && buffer[length-1] == '\n' )
            buffer[--length] = '\0';                    

        if ( length > 22 )
        {
            if(buffer[22] == 'O')
            {
                printf("ravroot, %c\n", buffer[22]);
                printf("%s*\n", buffer);
            }
            else if(buffer[22] == 'A')
            {
                printf("ravrate, %c\n", buffer[22]);
                printf("%s*\n", buffer);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(ifp);
    fclose(ofp);
    return(0);    
}
```

Comment: +1; but you shouldn't look at `buffer[22]` unless you know that you read at least 23 characters (which was also a problem in the OP's code).

Comment: thanks @user3386109. fgets hits the spot. finally got the output I wanted. :D

Comment: @pat good point. I had the length computed, should have checked.

Answer (score 0):

If every record is in seperate line thne use  the fgets function which will stop when the newline is encountered , eg:

```
 while(fgets(buf,LINESZ,ifp) != NULL)
 {
     //you can put your code here
 }
```

Comment: Hi @M Thotager. I revised my code and yeah it works! but when I fwrite the buffer, it only writes the first record. but the printf works out fine. DO you know why?